# HTML / CSS Popup div on text click

Tags: css, html, popup

I want to make popup div instead of popup window for my 'About' picture/page with current button like in this example:
[image: OMG! Ubuntu! Facebook like popup]

Comment: Questions asking for code should show a **minimum** understanding of the problem. This means you'll have to include attempted solutions, why they didn't work and the expected results **in your question**.

Comment: You may use: Reveal jQuery Modals: http://zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin

Answer (score 139, accepted):

**DEMO**

In the content area you can provide whatever you want to display in it — using the following code from https://gist.github.com/westonwatson/3914027 that I have copied in here:

```css
.black_overlay {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 1001;
  -moz-opacity: 0.8;
  opacity: .80;
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
.white_content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  padding: 16px;
  border: 16px solid orange;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1002;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>LIGHTBOX EXAMPLE</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>This is the main content. To display a lightbox click <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">here</a>
  </p>
  <div id="light" class="white_content">This is the lightbox content. <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">Close</a>
  </div>
  <div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Great code, but both positions should be `fixed`. If user clicks the link after having scrolled, the overlay & modal window go to the top of the page.

Comment: For anyone who is interested, if you want the overlay to "expand past"  the viewport (i.e. take over the whole page) Set the position to fixed. This will make it appear as though the whole page has the overlay.

Answer (score 15):

You can simply use [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Example:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#dialog").dialog();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The question asks for CSS, not Javascript.  CSS is less likely to be disabled at the browser.

Answer (score 8):

For the sake of completeness, what you are trying to create is a "modal window".

Numerous JS solutions allow you to create them with ease, take the time to find the one which best suits your needs.

I have used Tinybox 2 for small projects : 
http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/tinybox2/

Comment: The asker ask about HTML pop-up within the page, not "modal window".

Comment: I would NOT recommend TinyBox.
It's undocumented and the source code is obfuscated.
You'll have trouble all the time.