# Creating a DIV Popup Warning

Tags: html, css, popup, onload

On this example: [HTML / CSS Popup div on text click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19064987/html-css-popup-div-on-text-click)

How can I make this load on the index page when they visit the site the first time. I don't want a button to click, I want this load automatically; and then have a close button when they read the content on the popup. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do trying? Where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do this using  bootstrap model popup
for this include bootstrap css and js files and use below code

Your Html Code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  arialabelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Intorduction</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Body Text
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a  class="btn btn-default"  data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

then use this script

```
<script>
      if (localStorage.getItem('showModal')!='yes')
        {
        localStorage.setItem('showModal','yes');
        $('#myModal').modal('show');

        }

 </script>
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions that are unclear or bad, it encourages more bad questions.

Comment: i was able to understand thats why i replied