# Displaying selected row values in a popup

Tags: php, html, popup, radio-button

I have a table containing radio buttons, Below which I have series of buttons like Add, Delete , Details.

After selecting radio button and clicking on Details button, I need to get a popup that displays the selected row values.

Currently I have a details button that displays details below the main table.
This is my details button:

```
<input type="submit" name="details" value="Details" id="btndetails"   />
```

Here 'ID' is the name of my radio button.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['details']))
{
    $n=$_POST['ID'];
    $a=implode("</br>",$n);
    list($add,$place) = explode("(!@!)", $a);
    ?>
    <table id="Details">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <ul><?php echo"<b>Address:</b>$add</br>";?></ul>
    <ul><?php echo"<b>Place</b>$place</br>";?></ul>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
}
```

How can I display this deatils table as popup on selecting radio followed by clicking details button?please help. Thank u

Answer (score 1):

If you install the jQuery UI you can do it as simply as this.

```
$("btndetails").click(function(){
    $("#Details").bPopup();
});
```

Make Sure `<table id="Details">` has `style="display: none;"`

**EDIT**

Sorry, I forgot to add the specific popup UI is here: http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/

Comment: Once you include the UI javascript code in your files `<head>`, The popup could be written in another javascript file that can be included, or on the same html page in between `<script></script>` tags.

Comment: How to include UI javascript code in <head> please tel me ... @Mitch

Comment: Is there any method to use this popup without installing jQuery UI?

Comment: You could learn just pure css. I extremely advise against it as it is way more code and can be buggy (especially on older browsers).

Comment: BUT.... here is another article that shows you with pure css.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19064987/html-css-popup-div-on-text-click