# css popup disable scroll on page

Tags: css, popup

I am doing a popup light box by using the code I found in this article [HTML / CSS Popup div on text click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19064987/html-css-popup-div-on-text-click).

Now I am trying to disable the main scrolling of the page, since the light box  has a fixed height, but certain pages are longer then the popup which leads to scrolling the background of the popup which in this case is the page itself.

I played a bit with overflow but without success.

Comment: body {overflow: hidden} when your pop-up is active. You'll need javascript for this i guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following CSS:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Also, if you trigger this code on a random location in the page, you might need to do extra work.

Do you have a jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: sadly none of the above, but since its wordpress it will go straight to page template

Comment: the thing im trying to do is like here https://www.lush.co.uk/ just click the upperleft speechbubble

Comment: I can't write the whole layout for you. You need to give me something to work with. Do you have a live url where I can view actual code? Or can you copy-paste code in? Code that you're actually using.

Comment: sadly using localhost, but your and nikolays replyes gave me something to work on . thank you both :)

Comment: If your question is answered, you should mark one of the answers as the correct one. ;)

Comment: srry new here , still getting used to this , thanks :)